# R in 18.04 lockfile error in tmp directory when building a package: Bad Address

Tags: r, tmpfs

I am getting the following address when I try building a package in R.

```
> R CMD build bootLR
```

...

```
  cp: error writing '/tmp/RtmpIwkIfV/Rbuild1cf97228aeac/bootLR/.Rproj.user/6295459/sources/s-52F68146/lock_file': Bad address
    ERROR
   copying to build directory failed
```

Things I have tried:

- Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a new computer
- Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a new VM
- Deleting the lock file (it doesn't exist, nor do many of the directories higher than it in the directory heirarchy)
- Googling this error (nothing seems to exist on R specifically; it does seem to be a pointer issue within C perhaps?)
- Waiting 6 months, installing the now-latest R version
- Moving /tmp to a memory disk and rebooting

The best I've gotten it down to is to make the problem intermittent - it built the package once or twice, then started reporting the error again.

To reproduce, install R and all the packages I have installed:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
# Add to /etc/apt/sources.list: deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic/
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install r-base r-base-dev r-recommended libssl-dev libssh2-1-dev
sudo R
install.packages(c("Hmisc","R.utils"))
install.packages(c("RColorBrewer","RCurl","foreign"))
install.packages(c("data.table"))
install.packages(c("tidyverse"))
install.packages(c("functional","XML","MatchIt"))
install.packages(c("taRifx","taRifx.geo","taRifxRcpp","bootLR")) # my packages
install.packages(c("ggplot2","dplyr","stringr", "lubridate","devtools","Roxygen")) # Hadleyverse
install.packages(c("sp","spdep","rgdal","maptools"))
install.packages(c("SDMTools","gstat"))
install.packages(c("automap","RArcInfo","rgeos","spatstat","FNN","fields","MapGAM","spBayes","functional"))
install.packages(c("gtools","gdata","car","formula.tools"))
install.packages(c("testthat","MASS","stargazer","survey","xtable","pander"))
install.packages(c("formatR","caTools","rprojroot","rmarkdown"))
install.packages(c("zeligverse")) 
install.packages(c("boot","binom")) 
install.packages(c("ROAuth","twitteR","RJSONIO")) # webscraping
install.packages(c("pscl","bayesm","perturb","plm"))
install.packages(c("doParallel"))
install.packages(c("HH"))
install.packages(c("equivalence","ROCR","r2stl","svglite"))
```

Any help/tips you could offer, even as to where I should start looking for the problem, would be most appreciated.

Comment: Having asked this, of course I had an insight as soon as I posted.  It stopped working around the time I moved things to a SMB share.  Preliminary testing indicates that was the problem.  Will post that as the answer and close this if that remains true, so that others can benefit from my frustration.

Comment: @ari-b-friedman I have the same issue. Also on SMB... did you find a work around?